# preserving order of function implementation

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, composition

So I have a numeric value and on those two functions can be applied.

Lets say I have a number 8.

I want to take its square and then its log or first the log and then its square.

So my function looks something like this

```
def transform(value, transformation_list):
  # value is int, transformation_list = ["log",square"] or ["square","log"]
 # square function and log function
 return transformed value
```

Now if the first argument of the transformation list is "square" and the second is "log",
then it should first execute square and then log

But if the first function in that list is "log" and second " square" then it should implement first log and then square.

I dont want if : else kinda thing as it will get ugly as i add more transformations
How should I design this.

Comment: Is it required that the transformation list is a list of strings? You could just pass a list of functions (`from path import log; def square(x): return x * x; transform(8, [log, square])`).

Comment: can you write it as a solution and explain it a bit?  it doesnt have to be a list.. ??

Comment: It's probably not an answer, but my point is: Instead of passing a list of strings, you could make things easier and more extensible by passing a list of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
import math

func_dict = {'square': lambda x: x**2,
             'cube': lambda x: x**3,
             'log': math.log}

def transform(value, transformation_list):
    for func_name in transformation_list:
        value = func_dict[func_name](value)
    return value
```

For example:

```
>>> transform(math.e, ['cube', 'log', 'square'])
9.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52902-function-composition/) for function composition (or alternatively, using the [functional](http://oakwinter.com/code/functional/) module), you can compose an arbitrary list of functions - no need to pass the names as strings, simply pass the functions:

```
class compose:
    def __init__(self, f, g, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy()
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(self.g(*args, **kwargs), *self.pending, **self.kwargs)

def transform(value, transformation_list, inverted=False):
    lst = transformation_list if inverted else reversed(transformation_list)
    return reduce(compose, lst)(value)
```

Now you can call `transform` like this:

```
from math import *
value = 2
transformation_list = [sin, sqrt, log]
transform(value, transformation_list)
> -0.047541518047580299
```

And the above will be equivalent to `log(sqrt(sin(2)))`. If you need to invert the order of function application, for example `sin(sqrt(log(2)))`, then do this:

```
transform(value, transformation_list, inverted=True)
> 0.73965300649866683
```

Also, you can define functions in-line. For instance, F.J's example would look like this using my implementation:

```
transform(e, [lambda x:x**3, log, lambda x:x**2])
> 9.0
```